# Salesforce for both B2B & B2C -which model?

Tags: data, person-accounts

We are going with Salesforce and we are actually serving both B2B and B2C Clients.

Would you recommend the use of Person Accounts or you would go building some custom objects to replicate more or less the salesforce functionality? (For example, having record types on the lead & account object to differentiate the channels). What are the industry standards in such cases?

Thank you

Comment: You may want to read the answer I posted to a similar question: [salesforce-b2c-vs-b2b](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53694/salesforce-b2c-vs-b2b/53731#53731)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not going with Person Accounts if possible.  You could create some customizations to get you 'close' to having a Person Account without actually committing.  You are locked in once you go with Person Accounts, there is no de-activating it.  Your reporting will be funky.  It just adds a ton of complexity and confusion that give anyone attempting to maintain and improve your system more headaches than are necessary.  The list could go on and on.  If you really want to enable them, thats fine.  But keep in mind that Salesforce is also looking (not a clear date, hopefully Winter '16?!?!, to have the ability to make a "Person Custom Object".

If you have a really great reason that you should go with Person Accounts, then do it.  But if you have any ability to avoid it... avoid it!